# Typescript singleton causes infinite loop

Tags: typescript, singleton

I have a game class defined as a singleton. In the game's constructor, a new car instance is made. That car's constructor immediately uses the singleton to show a message.

This creates an infinite loop because the game instance is not yet saved in the static variable, so the singleton creates a new instance, which creates a new car, which creates a new instance...

Is this expected behavior of a Singleton in Typescript / Javascript?

**The Game class**

```
class Game {

    private static instance: Game;
    private car : Car;

    public static getInstance() {
        if (! Game.instance) {
            Game.instance = new Game();
        }
        return Game.instance;
    }

    private constructor() {
        this.car = new Car();
    }

    public showMessage(str){
        console.log(str);
    }
} 


// load
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    Game.getInstance();
});
```

**Car.ts**

```
class Car {

    private speed:number;

    constructor() {
        console.log("car created");

        // this causes an infinite loop!
        Game.getInstance().showMessage("hey there");

    }
}
```

Comment: it's expected behaviour of the code you wrote.. you should probably make the car class gets it's game instance at a later date. Or make the Game instiantiate cars after it sets the instance variable.

Comment: What did you expect? Your `Game` instance requires a `Car` and your `Car` instance requires a `Game`.

Comment: I expected the Singleton to keep its promise... to only ever return one single instance...

Comment: @Kokodoko Right now you can't even create a single instance of `Game` without blowing your call stack.

Comment: That's why I asked this question... :) I didn't expect the Singleton to be hackable :) I guess it makes sense.

Comment: This has nothing to do with singletons. The code is fundamentally wrong. You have a chicken-and-egg thing going on with your code. To implement a singleton you must be able to create an instance of a class which you cannot now.